# With the Pixel 2 supporting USB Audio Class 1/2/3, which USB audio devices work? Or *don't* work?

Tags: usb, audio, headphones, dock

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/phone-by-google/Yvy0RfOPFfU

> Pixel 2 supports audio adapters and headsets that communicate digitally over USB-C as defined by USB Audio Class 1/2/3.  Pixel 2 does not support an analog audio signal over USB-C and subsequently will display an unsupported notification warning when an analog audio device is attached.

Here's the spec documents from USB.org:

http://www.usb.org/developers/docs/devclass_docs/

So it got me thinking, what kinds of USB audio devices are actually supported?

- Audio mixers, like [this one from Behringer](https://www.sweetwater.com/store/detail/Q802USB)? Or does it only support USB output, not input? I have such a mixer, but I don't have a Pixel 2 to test.
- Car stereos, to my knowledge, have never supported any USB Audio Device class. I hope this changes, but all I've seen is support for USB mass storage mode (only old versions of Android), then MTP (only plays formats that the car stereo supports; no FLAC, maybe no AAC), and then [AOA v2](https://source.android.com/devices/accessories/protocol), which seems to have been abandoned for some reason (Pixel 2 doesn't support it, nor does the Moto X4).
- USB headphones: some recommended models are listed on the Google post I linked above. Are there any that you've found *not* to work?
- USB DACs/amps: [here's a thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/GooglePixel/comments/7an16s/external_dacsamps_pixel_2_will_it_finally_work/), they seem to be well supported.
- Speaker docks: they only support iPhones, don't they? Has any manufacturer chosen to make one for the Pixel 2, or are there any that support a class of USB Audio?

Comment: @mirh Not only is this thread 2 years old, but I was talking about devices you connect the phone to, not the phone itself...